# Azure IOTHub file upload 403: TooManyDevicesError

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

After following this simple guide step by step I'm getting the following error when I try to upload a single .tiff file to Azure

```
azure.iot.device.exceptions.ClientError: ClientError('Unexpected failure') caused by ServiceError('HTTP operation returned: 403 TooManyDevicesError(Error: Forbidden)')
```

I have only 2 devices configured in my IOTHub.

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the guide being mentioned on your post or the relevant piece of code that causes the exception if that's the case?

Comment: Which documentation are you following? How exactly are you uploading a file? What method are you using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload  
Are you uploading a concurrent file by any chance? Each device client is limited to 10 concurrent file uploads.